# How convert XML to STEP(p21) format?

Tags: c++, step, caa

I am new STEP and Express modeling. How can I convert XML data into STEP `"p21"` file using `C++ bindings` and CAA module? Where can I find a good tutorial for the EXPRESS modeling language? If I am missing something, suggest me to learn them. I would like someone to explain me the way we do it or show some guidelines to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitively take a look at the CAA V5 Encyclopedia. The chapter about ENOVIA V5 contains several articles such as:

> STEP Overview -   Understanding STEP, Express, and SDAI
>
> Building Components - How to build an Express schema
>
> Generating the ENOV_DATAX Data Structure -    How to migrate data to
>   ENOVIA

... as well as a few use cases and quick API reference.

Since you must use the CAA, you also have the option take a course directly from Dassault Systèmes

Comment: Thanks for the info. Where can i find CAA V5 Encyclopedia?..May be i am bit slow because i am new to this. I googled with the keyword "CAA V5 Encyclopedia", but i am lost. HELP ME..

Comment: Do we have any online help/tutorial for EXPRESS, CAA, SDAI and STEP? Can't we gain knowledge on CAA without taking a course from DS?

Comment: i got the access to CAA V5 encyclopaedia after i got installation in my working system. Is there any other way to learn CAA programming instead taking course from DS? I mean is there anyway to dive ourself into this encyclopaedia and gaining programming knowledge?..If so, can you give me the possible starting tips..